# Does encrypting the hard drive affect file sync with programs like Dropbox, Ubuntu One, Spider Oak, Insync, and others?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, encryption, dropbox, insync

For the last few months I've been having a lot of problems syncing with two computers that I reinstalled and encrypted the drives. It is happening with all the programs I mention in the subject. Can the encryption of the disk be the cause of the problem?

My encrypted SSD uses LUKS version 1, LVM2 PV

Update: My home does use ecryptfs. This is the relevant line of `df -T`:

`/home/ramon/.Private    ecryptfs 118659356  86991664  25633468  78% /home/ramon`

Comment: If you're speaking of encrypting the /home which gets decrypted for use when you boot into your machine, then not likely. If the disk remains encrypted while you're logged in, like with Truecrypt, then yes, it may. <br>
Are you getting any other errors?

Comment: Please specify how you're doing the encryption, in your question.

Comment: Also, please include the errors you're seeing, in your question.

Comment: Added the encryption info. I see no errors, the files just don't sync or take forever to sync (days).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/773260) which may be relevant, suggesting that some encrypted filesystems don't handle `inotify` events properly (and hence the syncronisation daemon doesn't detect changes to files, only differences it finds when it scans on startup).

It's unclear from the bug report whether this has been resolved or what the current status is, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the petition to clarify. Edited the question and added the encryption details.

Comment: @chronitis Does this mean that I have to reformat the computer and work without any encryption on my disk to be sure that the sync apps work properly?

Comment: Unclear, I'm afraid. Since the bug report is two years old with no activity in the last year I am uncertain whether associating it with your problem is correct.

Since you are sharing your data with a cloud service (whatever their security guarantees are claimed to be), encryption seems somewhat redundant, but having to reinstall is a big pain.

Comment: You can try testing whether `inotify` works in your encrypted folder by installing package `inotify-tools`, running `inotifywatch ~/Ubuntu\ One` in a terminal, edit some files in the U1 folder and then use Ctrl+C in the terminal to terminate `inotifywatch` and see if the summary lists any events. If it does, then your problem is _probably_ unrelated to the above bug (but I don't know enough detail about `inotify` to be sure).